# Website on Ajenti V with Node.JS content always throw 404

Tags: node.js

I install AjentiV to manage my website. Now I have an webapp on NodeJS and want to use with AjentiV. I follow a simple tutorial [Setting up a Node.js website with Ajenti V (Keystone example)](http://support.ajenti.org/topics/1123-setting-up-a-nodejs-website-with-ajenti-v-keystone-example/) . 
I config the Content of website to Node.JS, provide the script and config port 8080. I use port 8080 for the Node app, there are no error but I try the webapp always throw 404  - Not found result, in both port 80 and 8080.

Has anyone met this problem before? How can I make it works?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. There is no problem with AjentiV and Node.JS content. The problem itself is the our webapp always throw 404 due to my fault config.

Comment: Hello, can you put the step that you follow here please,
I'm using ajenti in my vps an I'd like to run nodejs app with PM but i don't know how I can do that from ajenti interface

Comment: @JFouad: I run nodejs with PM2 normally. Then in Ajenti, I follow the tutorial, except that in the Content entry -> Script, I input a randon word that keep the Ajenti cannot run our nodejs by that script.
Tutorial: http://support.ajenti.org/topics/1123-setting-up-a-nodejs-website-with-ajenti-v-keystone-example/